# Angular 12 > 13 upgrade and now getting "Can't bind X since it isn't a known property of X error

Tags: angular

Upgraded Angular 12 > 13.  All working fine.  Shut down computer, came back this morning having **not changed any code** and now I get the following error on every component with an @Input() binding.  These were all working fine before.

`Can't bind to 'X' since it isn't a known property of 'Y-component'.`

I've tried deleting the `package-lock.json` and `node_modules` folder and running `npm i` and that doesn't help.

I've checked for outdated dependencies with `npm outdated` and all are looking good.

I don't understand why exactly the same code would suddenly be erroring like this today.

An example of a binding I'm using:

`<page-load-feedback-component [pageLoadStatus]="pageLoadStatus"></page-load-feedback-component>`

And in the `page-load-feedback-component`:

```
@Input()
pageLoadStatus: number;
```

Error:

`Can't bind to 'pageLoadStatus' since it isn't a known property of 'page-load-feedback-component'.`

I've done this a million times.  No idea what's wrong.

Any thoughts welcome.  Thanks!

Comment: Thank you.  Solved it actually.  Sorry to have wasted your time.  Please see Answer.

Answer (score 0):

Solved!  After a couple of hours of looking at this I post this question and then solve it in a couple of minutes by looking elsewhere.

Turned out to be an import for `angular2-ladda` which had a broken path in the `app.module.ts`.